# Is it possible to make a folder look and behave like a file?

Tags: macos, finder, filesystem, development

I'm developing a desktop application which saves its projects to disk.  Projects contain multiple files, like `json` and `jpg` etc.

### Current solution: zipped file

I'm "zipping" them all together into a **single file**.  Example:

```
filename.project            <- compressed zip
  manifest.json             <- compressed contents
  file1.jpg
```

## Ideal solution: uncompressed folder

I'm wondering if it's possible to output the data, uncompressed, to a **folder** instead, and somehow configure my OS to treat that folder **as a single file**?  Example:

```
filename.project            <- folder, but it gets treated like a file
  manifest.json             <- uncompressed contents
  file1.jpg
```

Definition of "Treated as a single file":

- Finder shows a custom icon
- Double-clicking opens the file association
- "Open" dialogs can select this file

## Other examples

On my Mac, there are 2 examples where I see this happening:
 - All apps appear as `.app` files, but internally are folders that I can explore via Terminal
 - **1Password** stores its password store in a `.agilekeychain` folder, which syncs to Dropbox as a folder, but appears in Finder as a single file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple Developer info says yes, you can definitely make your own package or bundle. [Seems as if you want a package](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/DocumentPackages/DocumentPackages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH106-SW1).

[Package vs. bundle is discussed here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AboutBundles/AboutBundles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH100)

Basically - register your package with the system, so that folders with the extension are displayed as a package rather than as a folder (application info.plist must appropriately set key `LSTypeIsPackage` for each of the package filetypes you need to create). Then set your app to automatically (using `NSFileWrapper`) or manually create the package itself on save.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the information I was looking for!